# Pascal triangle - how to derive row-specific formula

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, proof-writing

Is there any way I can intuitively demonstrate or remember the formula listed at [Calculating a row or diagonal by itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle#Calculating_a_row_or_diagonal_by_itself) for the Pascal triangle?

I'm talking of

$$
{n\choose k}= {n\choose k-1}\times \frac{n+1-k}{k}
$$

I tried with a piece of paper and it definitely works.. but I don't know why. There is no proof or demonstration.. so: why does it work?

Comment: How do you define $\binom{n}{k}$ in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition (if you will),
$$
\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}.
$$
Now, if you already know
$$
\binom{n}{k-1} = \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-(k-1))!},
$$
then you just need to compensate for the difference in the denominator: that is, you need to "add" a factor $k$ to turn $(k-1)!$ into $k!$, and you need to "remove" a factor $n-(k-1)$ to turn $(n-(k-1))!$ into $(n-k)!$. To do this you multiply by the fraction
$$
\frac{n-k+1}{k}.
$$